# Microsoft.Extensions.Diagnostics.HealthChecks failure message

Tags: asp.net-core, diagnostics, health-monitoring

Asp.Net Core 2.2.0

For a failed health-check how to return

For example :

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.Diagnostics.HealthChecks;

public class SqlConnectionHealthCheck : IHealthCheck
{
    public async Task<HealthCheckResult> CheckHealthAsync(HealthCheckContext context, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken))
    {
        try
        {
            // attempt connection to db
        }
        catch(DbException ex)
        {
            return new HealthCheckResult(status: context.Registration.FailureStatus, exception: ex);
        }
```

When this fails the browser shows `Unhealthy`

How to display the exception message and the stack trace ?

Answer (score 0):

> How to display the exception message

```
// one option:
catch(DbException ex)
{
    return new HealthCheckResult(status: context.Registration.FailureStatus, description: exception.Message, exception: ex);
}
```

> and the stack trace

Are you sure you want to do that?

Comment: According to docs `Description` is read-only.  What are some reasons why I wouldn't want to display the exception message ?

Comment: @BaltoStar It was the stack trace that I thought you may want to reconsider.  Typically I avoid exposing the stack trace for security concern.